# Windows Form Application (Crystal Report Error )

Tags: c#, winforms, crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

Windows Form Application gives an error once I try to load data to crystal report (it runs on the local machine in visual studio) but failed only once I deploy this application on some other machine.

```
    **Error**
    
    ************** Exception Text **************
    CrystalDecisions.Shared.CrystalReportsException: Load report failed. ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: The document has not been opened.
       at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc.ReportClientDocumentClass.get_ReportAppServer()
       at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.get_ReportAppServer()
       at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
       --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
       at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ReportClientDocumentWrapper.EnsureDocumentIsOpened()
       at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
       at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass.Load(String reportName, OpenReportMethod openMethod, Int16 parentJob)
       at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.Load(String filename)
       at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.NonHTTPCachedReportSource.GetReport(RequestContext context, Boolean bAddToCacheWhenCreated)
       at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.LocalReportSourceBase.GetAvailableExportFormats(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
       at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ViewerDocument.GetAvailableExportFormats()
       at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.PageView.CreateReportDocument(String rptURI)
       at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.PageView.CreateNewReportDocument(String pageName)
       at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer.CreateReportSource(Object reportSource)
       at CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.CrystalReportViewer.set_ReportSource(Object value)
       at ZM_RealState.Screens.DashBoard.GetEmptyInvoice_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.Callback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
```

Comment: And the directory structure on the problem machine is identical to the working dev machine? The problem machine definitely has CR runtimes installed and they're the correct bitness compared to your app?

Comment: Thank you for your response, @caius Jard                                           I have installed the CR runtime, it still throws the same error, would it be possible I can share the screen with you and look for the issue. Its been one week am looking for a solution, I have checked all SAP forums tried all the work around

Comment: Did you certainly install the exact version of the runtime that the code is looking for?

Comment: Could you please paste the code